# How to download file on button click in grid vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I m trying to download file on button click and button is present in a grid column vaadin. how can i achieve this

```
Button tempDownloadBtn = new Button();
tempDownloadBtn.setId("tempdownloadbtn");
Grid tableList = new Grid();
tableList.addColumn("title", String.class).setHeaderCaption("TITLE").setSortable(false);
tableList.addColumn("creationDate", String.class).setHeaderCaption("CREATION DATE").setSortable(false);
tableList.addColumn("status", String.class).setHeaderCaption("STATUS").setSortable(false).setWidth(120).setRenderer(new HtmlRenderer());
tableList.addColumn("description", String.class).setHeaderCaption("DESCRIPTION").setSortable(false);
tableList.addColumn("transactionType", String.class).setHeaderCaption("TRANSACTION TYPE").setSortable(false);
tableList.addColumn("batchId", String.class).setSortable(false).setHidden(true);
tableList.addColumn("action", String.class).setHeaderCaption("ACTION").setSortable(false).setRenderer(new ButtonRenderer(e -> {
    Indexed indexed = tableList.getContainerDataSource();
    String action = indexed.getContainerProperty(e.getItemId(), "action").getValue().toString();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Download Passcode"))
    {
        String batchId = Encrypter.decodeString(indexed.getContainerProperty(e.getItemId(), "batchId").getValue().toString());
        DownloadVoucherDetailsResponseM downloadFileResponseM = new CommonB().dowloadVoucherDetails(batchId);
        if (downloadFileResponseM.getResponseCode().equals("0000"))
        {
            System.out.println("DOWNLOAD_FILE_PATH::: " + downloadFileResponseM.getFilePath());
            File downloadFile = new File(downloadFileResponseM.getFilePath());

            FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(new FileResource(downloadFile));
            fileDownloader.extend(tempDownloadBtn);

            Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("document.getElementById('tempdownloadbtn').click();");
        }
    }
}));
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is not possible to use FileDownloader with Grid and ButtonRenderer because you have no Button component for each row at hand. 1.) Try Vaadin Table where you can generate the button for each row and use FIleDownloader. Or 2.) Find another way for downloads when using Grid and click event handler of ButtonRenderer.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please share it.

Comment: No. After alot of search on google i didn't find any solution for this then i decided to move on table.

Comment: Stumbled across a Vaadin add on that could have helped: [GridFileDownloader](https://github.com/Ansku/GridFileDownloader)

Comment: Vaadin 8.1 should allow having components within grid, but better design could be to open window as result of item selection and then implement inside popup window button which does downloading. I will try this, since to me Table is not an option as it is effectively (almost) deprecated.

Comment: This add-on may help, too: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/componentrenderer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
    Button downloadButton = new Button();
    downloadButton.setIcon(FontAwesome.DOWNLOAD);

```
File file = new File("D:\\..\\sample.txt");

StreamResource.StreamSource source = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4367295093982409180L;

    public InputStream getStream() {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            /* e.printStackTrace(); */
        }
        return in;

    }
};
StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, file.getName());
resource.setCacheTime(1);

FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(resource);
fileDownloader.extend(downloadButton);
```

Comment: I think this is right way to implement download, but one doesn't simply manage to integrate button and grid in vaadin 7.x and 8.0. At least I don't know how to fire click event of button as result of grids item selection.